# My account and my questions have been deleted

Tags: support, moderation

Can a moderator please look into this? It would be very important as I need my account urgently. I had 30 favorite questions there that I need to reference in a research paper that I have to hand in by tomorrow!!

[My account and my questions have been deleted](https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216/my-account-and-my-questions-have-been-deleted)

Comment: If you haven't already, flag the questions you posted and request help - if the moderators aren't hanging around on that meta, they might not know you need help.  Flagging will put it front and center for any mods working on the site now.

Comment: @AdamDavis FWIW, mods on SE2.0 sites get global inbox notifications any time somebody posts a new question on the site meta

Comment: I can see your faves.  Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/users/338825/bizso09?tab=favorites

Comment: I need my favs on quant.stackexchange http://quant.stackexchange.com/users/1681/bizso09?tab=favorites

Comment: @JNK This is a new account he created today, and he's talking about QF, not SO

Comment: Looks like your question's been answered on [meta.quant.se]. Closing here.