# Flagging as off-topic on meta - like flogging a dying bird?

Tags: flags, off-topic, discussion

Whenever I see an off-topic question, I instinctively vote to close. On meta where I'm still way shy of the required rep, I'll resort to flagging it as off-topic.

Question is, **is off-topic flagging necessary/helpful on meta**? Considering the lower volume of questions, I'm assuming it's unlikely that the question will survive long enough to drop off the front page anyway.

Looking at the most recent "close as off-topic" questions ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112725/134327), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112706/134327), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112675/134327), [4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112531/134327), [5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112529/134327)), all were closed within 30 minutes (except the second which wasn't a clear-cut off-topic question).

Right now, flagging on meta makes me feel like a Flag Wh0r3<sup><sup>TM</sup></sup>.

Comment: Yes, of course. If a question belongs on StackOverflow rather than Meta.StackOverflow flag away. It happens a few times each day, so get that flag weight up!

Comment: Eh, don't sweat it.  Due to the mod-to-posts-per-day ratio OT questions get handled pretty quickly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Right now, flagging on meta makes me feel like a Flag Wh0r3.

Then embrace your Flag Wh0r3ity, and savour every succulent bit of flag weight you gain this way! :)

Seriously, I don't think it's a problem. Flag away - if it helps close a question faster, good; if not, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Sounds good to me. A-wh0r1ng I shall go then... :)